# Warning message needed when there is no specific layer instead of python error

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

In my plugin, when I click a button it will call the findTheCityNames function which is attached below and get features if there is a particular layer. What I want is if there is no specific layer in which it is getting features, it should give a warning message "No Valid layer found" instead python error "List object has no attribute getFeatures".

```
def findTheCityNames(self):
    self.dlg.Citycombo.clear()
    ct = self.dlg.Statecombo.currentText()
    st = "state='"+ct+"'"
    exp = QgsExpression(st)
    fidAndVal = {}        
    #QMessageBox.information(self.dlg, "info", st) 

    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()

    iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()

    for f in iterFeat:
        val = exp.evaluate(f)
        if bool(val):
            attrs = f.attributes()
            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
            cityName = f.attributes()[idx]
            fidInt = f.id()
            fidAndVal[fidInt] = cityName

    for x in fidAndVal.keys():
        self.dlg.Citycombo.addItem(fidAndVal[x])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is most a python related question rather than a GIS question.

You can try with the "Try and except" in python sort of:

```
try:
   layer with possible problem
except:
   print this layer doesn't work.
```

Anyways I think is better to ask or search this in the python related StackExchange.

Comment: Python is case sensitive so perhaps change to `try` and `except` even though you are only presenting pseudo-code.

Comment: Thank you so much Gsanez. Really great! though my question is simple.